# Pie chart cannot be resized pyspark

Tags: matplotlib, pyspark, databricks, spark-notebook

I am trying to get a pie-chart displayed in a databricks notebook. The code to display it works, what doesnt work is size adjustments.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwpLb.png)

Ive tried the plt.figure(figsize=()) method, no change. Tried the ax.pie(..., radius=1800, frame=True). Did not work. The plot remains the same with the legend covering the entire plot and no legible data.